# Kendo UI Grid adding new record not posting data to server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on Kendo UI jQuery grid CRUD. I can get data display in the grid, but not adding new records.

When I click the update button to add a record after filling up columns in the pop-up window, nothing is posted to the server side as every property has a null value.
The picture shows what I got when the button is pressed.

[image]

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddLostProperty(LostPropertyViewModel lostProperty)
{
    try
    {
        using (var dbContext = new DBEntities())
        {
            if (lostProperty != null)
            {
                var newLostProperty = new sz_LostProperty()
                {
                    Name = lostProperty.PropertyName,
                    CategoryId = dbContext.sz_PropertyCategory.Where(x => x.Name == lostProperty.CategoryName).Select(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Description = lostProperty.PropertyDescription,
                    FoundDate = lostProperty.FoundDate,
                    FoundLocation = lostProperty.FoundLocation,
                    CratedDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date,
                    CratedBy = ""
                };

                dbContext.sz_LostProperty.Add(newLostProperty);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();

                return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "The Property has been added." });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "No lost property added." });
            }
        }
    }            
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Error: " + e });
    }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var serviceBaseUrl = "@Request.Url.ToString()",
            lostPropertyDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    create: {
                        url: serviceBaseUrl + "/AddLostProperty",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        complete: function (e) {
                            $('#manageLostPropertiesGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                        }
                    },
                    read: {
                        url: serviceBaseUrl + "/GetLostProperties",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: serviceBaseUrl + "/UpdateLostProperty",
                        type: "PUT",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: serviceBaseUrl + "/DeleteLostProperty",
                        type: "DELETE",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                pageSize: 20,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "PropertyId",
                        fields: {
                            PropertyId: { editable: false, nullable: true, type: "number" },
                            PropertyName: { type: "string", editable: true, validation: { required: true } },
                            CategoryId: { type: "number", editable: true, validation: { required: true } },
                            PropertyDescription: { validation: { required: false } },
                            Image: { validation: { required: false } },
                            FoundDate: { type: "Date" },
                            FoundLocation: { editable: true, validation: { required: false } }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        $("#manageLostPropertiesGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: lostPropertyDataSource,
            pageable: true,
            height: 550,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                { field: "PropertyName", title: "Property Name", width: "150px" },
                { field: "CategoryName", title: "Category", editor: propertyCategoryList,/* template: "#=CategoryName#", */width: "150px"},
                { field: "PropertyDescription", title: "Description", width: "200px" },
                { field: "FoundDate", title: "Found Date", template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(FoundDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy'), 'dd-MM-yyyy') #",  width: "130px" },
                { field: "FoundLocation", title: "Found Location", width: "120px" },
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
            editable: "popup"
        }).data("kendoGrid");
});
```

From the browser, I can see the object sent to the server below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the network console in your browser? What exactly is sent to the server?

Comment: @CarstenFranke Yes, I did. I uploaded the data which was sent to the server. Seems the answer below dressed the problem. The `parameterMap` was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that in this case is problem in your parameter type at server side.

You have enabled *batch: true* editing which is useful if you want make many changes in your grid but send only one request with changed models in the end. It is very useful for example in case of *inCell* edit mode, when you would see many many requests and so decrease them is something you want, but in case of popup edit, I personally do not see any reason to use batch editing, but yes, I know Telerik has this in their demo.

So, because *batch* editing is enabled, there is called [parameterMap](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.parametermap) before request is executed. (note: parameterMap is called only if you have batch edit enabled, otherwise it's ignored). That parameterMap wraps all your models into json string array and send that array with request to the server. In your case, there is always one record edited, but it doesn't matter - it will be sent as an array (in json string format).

Because it is sent as serialized string, you can

1) Change parameter of your AddLostProperty method to *string models* and then deserialize into array which allows you to work with it as you are used to

```
public ActionResult AddLostProperty(string models)
{
    ...
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<LostPropertyViewModel>>(models);
    ...
}
```

2) If we will follow Telerik demo, you can use such implementation

```
public ActionResult AddLostProperty()
{
    var products = this.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<LostPropertyViewModel>>("models");
    if (products != null)
    {
        //logic
    }
    return this.Jsonp(products);
}
```

3) And this is solution I would prefer

Just remove *batch: true* and *parameterMap* (since without batch it's useless) - and it should start send single object to your server method.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'd choose the 3rd solution to remove `parameterMap` since I add one record each time.